# What is the purpose of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools?

Tags: asp.net, macos, razor, visual-studio-code

What is the purpose of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools?

I'm using visual studio code on os x

From the git hub page https://github.com/aspnet/RazorTooling I can see

> The Razor syntax provide a fast, terse, clean and lightweight way to combine server code with HTML to create dynamic web content. This repo contains tooling that interacts with the DNX Design Time Host to provide a Razor editing experience.

Does visual studio code use this assembly? What is a DNX Design Time Host? When would I need to include this assembly in a project?

I found a reference to it in the project.json of a web application project that I generated using `yo aspnet`.

Answer (score 2):

At least here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools/ you can see a brief description of library:

> TagHelper tooling for .NET Core CLI. Contains the dotnet-razor-tooling
>   command used to resolve TagHelperDescriptors for projects at
>   design-time.

And here you can find a bit more details: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro.html#intellisense-support-for-tag-helpers

On mac you can run the same command:

```
dotnet razor-tooling
```

but it doesn't make any sense because for now VS Code doesn't provide any intenseness for Razor views. So probably you can remove this dependency from project.json.